# Sports modelling

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

In the last years I've discovered a field of maths that I like very much: Models. I graduated in Maths and I'd like investigate into sport models. Can you recommend a book o some paper to begin with? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to narrow this a fair bit. Sport models in what sense? Modeling win probabilities, for example, is rooted in Bayesian statistics. Mathematical modeling is a broad subject in general.

Comment: This is nice to read https://www.amazon.com/Operations-Research-Applications-Algorithms-InfoTrac/dp/0534380581

Comment: This is a paper on Sports Scheduling Problem https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167637720300225

Comment: I don’t know at the moment which part of sport modelling I’d like discover. Anyway, thank you a lot, I’ll read with pleasure.